# How to prevent Parent bone rotates the child bone in pose mode in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rigging, constraints, inverse-kinematics, axis

As you can see in the figure 1 , I have one child bone connected to the parent , Although I locked all the rotation axis(fig 1) and applied limit rotation constraint to the child bone; when I move parent in the pose mode the child bone is moving(as shown in fig 2).
I want to prevent that rotation.I am a beginner in rigging. Please Help!

FIG 1:

[image: Parent Child , Locked axis of child]

FIG 2:
[image: Rotation of Parent Bone affecting the child bone]

Comment: a bone can be child of another but you can disable its Inherit Rotation option in the Properties panel > Bone > Relations. Maybe it's what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep,That's what I was looking for. Thank you @moonboots!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bone can be child of another but you can disable its *Inherit Rotation* option in the *Properties panel > Bone > Relations*.

Comment: Yep , Thanks for the answer